# UML use-cases and iterations

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

How can I represent in a UML use case's diagram the fact that an action is iterative? For example: actor Admin can add new categories and new subcategories. A subcategory can have other subcategories, so admin can add a new subcategory in a subcategory. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an UML use case, you do not model the process, but the features ...

So you can't ...

Next time, at least provide your own schema to show that you worked at least a little ...

And if you provide some works, you could get a more helpful answer ...

Comment: I've done my schema but it's in another language. So, you think it's not possible to show an iterative behaviour in a use-case? Maybe I can show this in the specifications of the uc?

Comment: what do you mean in another language ? In UML you can not show process in a use case schema, this is not its goal. For that you have several choices: textual description, activity diagram, sequence diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a use-case diagram is accompanied by a document describing its basic and alternate flows. Iterative behavior may described in the those [flows](http://www.gatherspace.com/static/use_case_example.html#8) (steps).